# JavaScript - for loops on x and y axes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, path-finding, a-star

I'm using a [A* pathfinding script](http://www.briangrinstead.com/blog/astar-search-algorithm-in-javascript-updated) in a simple JavaScript 2D (canvas) game. I broke my game down to a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). Anyway, my game is 15 columns across and 10 rows down.

**What is the problem?** Setting up the graph, the nodes are only set up 11 times across and 10 times up and down. The `X` axis should be up to `15` when appearently it only sets up to `grid.length` which is `11`. OK, so there is my problem. My `grid` is a return `array` included in the `SSCCE`.

Here is my `SSCCE`.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>    
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='graphstar.js'></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var board;
</script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='astar.js'></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function()
{
        // UP to DOWN - 11 Tiles (Y)
        // LEFT to RIGHT - 16 Tiles (X)
        graph = new Graph([
        [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], 
        [1, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 1], 
        [1, 13, 1, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 13, 13, 1], 
        [1, 13, 1, 1, 13, 1, 1, 13, 1, 13, 13, 1, 13, 13, 13, 1], 
        [1, 13, 13, 1, 1, 1, 13, 13, 1, 13, 13, 1, 1, 1, 13, 1], 
        [1, 13, 13, 1, 13, 1, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 1, 13, 13, 13, 1], 
        [1, 13, 13, 13, 13, 1, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 1, 13, 13, 13, 1], 
        [1, 13, 1, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 1, 1, 1, 1, 13, 13, 13, 1], 
        [1, 13, 1, 1, 1, 1, 13, 13, 13, 13, 1, 13, 13, 13, 13, 1], 
        [1, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 1], 
        [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
        ]);
        //Let's do an example test.
        start = graph.nodes[1][2]; // X: 1, Y: 2
        end = graph.nodes[12][7]; // X: 12, Y: 7
        result = astar.search(graph.nodes, start, end);
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
Loading... pathfinding. Look in Chrome Console/Firefox Firebug for more information.
</body>
</html>
```

As you can see, my `grid` is `11` rows up and down and `16` columns across. However my `graph` doesn't interpret it that way.

See the whole `graphstar.js` here: http://pastebin.com/KfS9ALFq (Here is `astar.js` for full package: http://pastebin.com/8WyWnTpQ)

This is where it's laid out in `graphstar.js`:

```
function Graph(grid) {
    var nodes = [];

    var row, rowLength, len = grid.length;
    console.log("Length:" + len);
    for (var x = 0; x < len; ++x) {
        row = grid[x];
        rowLength = row.length;
        nodes[x] = new Array(rowLength);
        for (var y = 0; y < rowLength; ++y) {
            nodes[x][y] = new GraphNode(x, y, row[y]);
        }
    }

    this.input = grid;
    this.nodes = nodes;
}
```

As you can see, the `for` loop only goes to the `grid.length` (`len`) which is `11` because it is `11` rows down. BUT That's the `X` axis.  My map for the `X` axis goes `15` columns across and the `Y` axis is `16` rows down.

Now you say... **why don't you switch the axis's around?** I tried that. Like, `X` and `Y` being switched. But all I get is `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property '0' of undefined` in `line 24` which is `nodes[x][y] = new GraphNode(x, y, row[y]);`

How can I make it so the graph is set up accordingly with `X`'s highest axis is `15` and `Y`'s highest axis is `10`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT:  Misinterpreted what you were saying.

It seems like you just need to change the way you're iterating through with the for loops so that you're going down one and across it, down one and across it

```
var row, rowLength, len = grid.length;
for(y = 0; y == len - 1; ++y) {
    row = grid[x];
    rowLength = row.length; // Expected: 16;
    nodes[y] = new Array(len);
    for (var x = 0; x == rowlength - 1; ++x){

            //figure out your nodes[y][x] here;
    }
}
```

Comment: I get the following error running this. `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '8' of undefined  ` Where `8` is the number for where I clicked on the `Y` axis.